# How to place text in front of an image in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So I need to position text next to an image using bootstrap. It should look something like:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQiE4.jpg)

The code I have:

```
<div id="picture">
        <img src="img/preview.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div id="description">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br> 
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <br> 
        It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656614291920-80ff97b2cf35?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw5fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        <br> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <br> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-Bootstrap works on 12 grid systems.

- ```row`` contains 12 grid.
- we can divide all 12 grid with `col`.
  for your lay out I have divided it into `col-8` for image and `col-4` for text.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-8">
     <img>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
     //content
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but not quite right. How to reduce the space between image and text?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/ explore it apply some css there are many classes as well

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<div class="row">

<img class="col-6"  src="">
<p class="col-6">line one <br> line two</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using bootstrap's conventional layout (12 cols grid)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="" alt="picture"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      "content"
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```